# Order of bean Creation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a controller

```
package com.controller;
    @Controller
    public class MyController{
    @Autowired
    private ISessionHolder holder;
    }
```

In my `config xml`:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />

<bean id="sessionholder" class="com.session.SessionHolder" scope="session">
    <aop:scopedProxy/>
</bean>
```

However I get the exception

```
no matching bean found for type ISessionHolder used in MyController.
```

But if i remove the bean definition for the sessionholder in the XML and annotate, it works fine.

```
@Component
@ScopedProxy
public class SessionHolder{
//
}
```

Are annotated classes instantiated first Or is there a specific order?

Comment: Does it work without the scope="session"?

Comment: Are you sure that the xml file is being used?

Comment: @gkamal edited my xml definition.

Comment: @gkamal will it work if I move the <context:component-scan> below my bean definition

Comment: Did you remove the @Component annotation when the bean was defined in xml?  If you have both the ids should match -  use "sessionHolder" as id then the xml definition will override annotation. Otherwise you will have two beans and then autowiring will fail.

Comment: No I removed the @component when I defined the bean in xml.kindly look at my previous comment and tell me if that is the prob.

Comment: The order doesn't matter - the configuration should work. There is something else wrong.  The SessionHolder class should implement the ISessionHolder interface.

Comment: I think gkamal is right.  You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233766/what-is-the-precedence-of-spring-beans-definitions XML always gets precedence