# Spring configuration class to inject bean as property

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having a spring configuration class which I am using to read from properties file and create the beans.

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:conf.properties")
    public class ApplicationConfiguration {

        @Value("${name}")
        private String username;

        @Value("${password}")
        private String password;

        @Value("${ethnicity}")
        private String ethnicity;

         @Bean 
           public Employee employee(){
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            ConfigParam configParam = new ConfigParam();
            configParam.setEthnicity(ethnicity);
            emp.setConfigParam(configParam);   
            return emp;
           }
    }
```

Inside the xml file

```
  <property name="configParam">
        <bean class="com.test.config.ConfigParam">
            <property name="ethnicity" value="indian" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```

I am able to set the `username` and `password` properties but unable to set the `configParam` attribute to `employee` since we need to inject the `ConfigParam`and its a `bean`. Please let me know how to inject a bean inside the `employee` method.

Comment: Where is the `ConfigParam` bean being defined? Normally you would add it as a parameter to the `employee()` method but I can't see that so not sure if that is the right solution.

Comment: What doesn't work? Seems you are setting your ethnicity to ConfigParam and ConfigParam to your employee bean. What more do you want? You could create ConfigParam as a bean and directly inject the ethnicity there, of course, but the end result would probably be the same... If you do not need to access ConfigParam as a bean, why create it as one?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my code. Just checking if we can define a `config` in the xml file and inject the bean to `emp` inside the `employee` function?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend mixing xml and Java config, because it tends to complicate things ("Where is this bean defined?" isn't easy anymore, since it could be code or xml). But yes, you should be able to do so. You can mix all these things. You could also define the configParam as it's own bean completely and then just `<ref bean="configParam"/>` into the Employee properties. Or you could use JavaConfig then... `public Employee employee(ConfigParam configParam) { ... }`

Comment: please post the `Employee` class and the full spring xml configuration. Also as mentioned by @FlorianSchaetz , dont mix xml/java configurations , because one of the two is ignored/overriden

Comment: @AntJavaDev Really? As long as they don't contradict somehow (or insert other logical problems), both can be used together. I just wouldn't advise it, because while it works, it tends to be pretty confusing. Having your configuration away from the logic... Good. Having your configuration in various formats... No so good, if you ask me.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz ....................................if you try to create the same bean  with the same name both in xml and in java configuration , wont work as expected , which is smth that from the given xml configuration we cannot imagine , so it is not the case you describe(also you could try it by yourself , you will see that the constructor will get called twice , but at the end only one bean will be kept in the context). The answer provided from @dimitrisli , does the trick , but ONLY in case that `Employee` bean is not defined again in the xml config

Comment: @AntJavaDev - Even if you got two beans, it wouldn't work, since then autowiring would fail because it doesn't know which to inject, one would have to be primary, etc. That's what I meant with "contradict". But thanks, I wasn't aware that XML config can override JavaConfig (or otherwise), I just assumed two beans would be created. But if you used the same name in xml and javaConfig, then I assume, it's logical that only one bean ends up being in the context.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz , check this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866379/its-ok-to-define-2-same-beans-in-xml-and-configuration) , because i dont have time right now to create a sample project just for your information

Comment: @AntJavaDev Wasn't doubting you there, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Spring XML context that includes the `configParam` definition is called `my-spring-context.xml` and is found in a `resources/spring` folder, in other words in a spring `folder` in your classpath (name and folder are arbitrary):

Make your `ApplicationConfiguration` configuration class aware of that XML context file by using the `@ImportResource` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/my-spring-context.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:conf.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
//...
}
```

Then in your `employee` method dependency-inject the XML bean as usual. If you want to inject by name and not by type you can add the `@Qualifier("myBeanName")` directly prior the `configParam` argument definition.

```
  @Bean
  @Autowired 
  public Employee employee(ConfigParam configParam){
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    configParam.setEthnicity(ethnicity);
    emp.setConfigParam(configParam);   
    return emp;
  }
```