# Which have more priority: Spring annotation or xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring, annotations

If i have a `spring bean` defined using both `xml` configuration and `annotation`. Then while initialization, which have more priority, `xml` or `annotations`.

Like my bean is...

```
package com.abc;    

@Component
Class Demo{
    ...
}
```

And my `xml` configuration is...

```
...
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc" />

<bean id="demo" class="com.abc.Demo"/>
...
```

Now the `demo` bean is defined using both `xml` and `annotations`. While initialization, who is initializing `bean`: `annotation` or `xml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example the default name for the bean created by @Component would be "demo", matching your XML, so only a single bean will be created - the instance created by the XML.

If the XML specified a different name (or the `@Component` annotation gave a different name), two instances would be created.

Comment: No, after giving different name also only one `bean` is getting initialized, which is in `xml`.

Comment: I just tried it myself and got 2 beans - single bean with same name (with properties set from XML) or 2 beans if the names are different. Tested by logging from the constructor so I see 1 or 2 log messages output

Comment: I've seen this behaviour many times - usually once a bean has more than one instance I remove the @Component annotation and define both in XML just so it's totally clear.

Comment: Ok, i am getting two beans. But if name is same, then  probably none is having priority as `spring container` is checking both of them.

Comment: No, the behaviour is consistent, the XML instance will always be used if defined

Comment: And with same name like, if in `xml` bean is marked `eager` and in annotation it is marked `@lazy`, then?

Comment: I tried, only a single bean is created, but with which(lazy or eager)?

Comment: Have you tested that? Set different property values in the XML and see if that's what you get... If my answer is correct then it will be the instance from the XML.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233766/what-is-the-precedence-of-spring-beans-definitions

Answer (score 4):

Annotation injection is performed before XML injection. Thus, the latter configuration will override the former for properties wired through both approaches.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this posting](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?57035-Precedence-of-XML-vs-Annotation-configuration&p=190416#post190416), you can't combine "component-scan" and XML-based wiring for the same classes.  It seems to say that you will end up instantiating the beans twice.

Comment: No, the `bean` is getting initialized only once.

Answer (score 1):

Annotation injection is performed before XML injection, thus the latter configuration will override the former for properties wired through both approaches.

In other words, XML configuration has higher priority than annotation configuration.

And, this doesn't mean you lost all annotation features such as unchecked exception support defined by @Repository or transactional support if you use @Transactional.

All annotations are still there and they are supported properly. The only difference is you end up with one bean definition instead of two.

Comment: the first 2 statements are contradictory

Comment: Annotation injection is performed before XML injection. XML configuration will override the annotation injection

Comment: If annotation runs first then annotation has higher priority over xml config.

Answer (score 0):

in case if you declare bean both in xml and using annotation, this leads container to read twice the bean's recipe.
if resulting bean name of xml differs from annotation's, it would lead to creation of 2 beans with different names!
what even more worse is that their behavior may vary if the recipe differs, f.ex. you declare @Scope("session") only 
using annotation only one bean would be session scoped and another singleton