# Example of xml config taking precedence over annotation config in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, xml-configuration

In a book I have read, that XML configuration has higher priority than annotation configuration.

But there aren't any examples of it.

Could you show an example of it?

Comment: check this post, i think everything is in there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233766/what-is-the-precedence-of-spring-beans-definitions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing a mix of xml based Spring config and Java based Spring config. There are 5 files in the example:

```
Main.java
AppConfig.java
applicationContext.xml
HelloWorld.java
HelloUniverse.java
```

Try running it first with the `helloBean` bean commented out in the applicationContext file and you will notice that the `helloBean` bean is instantiated from the AppConfig configuration class. Then run it with the `helloBean` bean uncommented in the applicationContext.xml file and you will notice that the xml defined bean takes precedence over the bean defined in the AppConfig class.

Main.java

```
package my.test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( AppConfig.class );
      ctx.getBean("helloBean"); 
   }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
package my.test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@ImportResource({"my/test/applicationContext.xml"})
public class AppConfig {

   @Bean(name="helloBean")
   public Object hello() {
      return new HelloWorld();
   }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="helloBean" class="my.test.HelloUniverse"/>

</beans>
```

HelloUniverse.java

```
package my.test;

public class HelloUniverse {

   public HelloUniverse() {
      System.out.println("Hello Universe!!!");
   }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package my.test;

public class HelloWorld {

   public HelloWorld() {
      System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
   }
}
```

Comment: @Tom There could be yet better answers :-). It is not the end yet.

Comment: @Tom It's OK. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

XML based configurations are used when we prefer centralized, declarative configurations of XML files. And when many of the configurations change. It gives you a clear idea how these configurations are wired. XML based is more loosely decoupled than annotation based.