# How to avoid beans with same id?

Tags: java, spring, inject

I have a problem familiar with this [bean override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233766/what-is-the-precedence-of-spring-beans-definitions)

2 beans are with same id, but their package is different.
Bean A was overridden by bean B. 
I spent lots of time to find the cause.

So I want to prevent the case. My request is that the spring throw a exception then shutdown the process of initializing if encounter case like this.

Comment: At first glance, I misread the title as "How to avoid bears with the same id" ... and thought that the ids were probably irrelevant :-)

Comment: why not use package name along with bean name?

Comment: `@Qualifier` may be helpful to you..

Comment: team work. 2 guys give a same id to their bean with same name but different package.

Comment: Then go talk to these 2 guys and let at least one of them change the name of their bean.

Comment: How are these beans configured? XML? Annotations? Named?

Comment: @Jesper that way cannot avoid anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can `@Inject` (`@Autowire`) by type, not by id. Read on [Autowiring collaborators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire).

Answer (score 0):

Spring can't have two beans with the same id in one context. So solution is obvious - use different ids.

If you are using xml context it should be :

```
<bean id="foo" class="what.ever.foo.Class" />

<bean id="bar" class="what.ever.package1.Class" />
```

If you are using annotations and component scan:

```
@Component("foo")
@Component("bar")
```

Annotation based context use different method names:

```
   @Bean
   public Foo foo() {
      return new Foo();
   }
   @Bean
   public Bar bar() {
      return new Bar();
   }
```